# How do I stop Safari underlining text in linked images?

Tags: safari

I have images linked to text in my site. The text appears like a link and when hovered over an image appears in a fixed position on the screen with text underneath it to describe it. I want the text under the image to appear plain and with no underline. It does in IE9, Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari. The html for the text link looks like this:-

```
    <p><a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb">Basil Thomas Stirratt<span><img src="images/basil     stirrat.jpg" width="200" height="299" alt="" /><br />Basil Thomas Stirratt<br />taken June 1940</span></a>, who was 18 at the time, had been......</p>
```

The css looks like this:-

```
.thumbnail{
background-color:#FFFF00;
position:static;
z-index: 0}

.thumbnail:hover{
background-color:#CCCCCC;
z-index: 50}

.thumbnail span{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
position:fixed;
background-color:#99CCFF;
padding:5px;
left: -1000px;
border: 10px ridge #E0E0E0;
visibility: hidden;
text-decoration:none;
text-indent:0px;
font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
color:#000000;
text-align:center;
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px #333333;
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px #333333;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px #333333;}

.thumbnail span img{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
border-width: 0;
padding: 2px;}
```

Strangely I do not seem to be allowed to post images to demonstrate the problem. To see how these images appear check out my website at [1]: http://www.wellingtont2905.co.uk/story.html, look for yellow highlighted text and hover your cursor over it.

Any suggestions for how I stop Safari doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Have sorted the problem. It has to do with having normal links underlined in my text, which I want. The solution has been to make the links a darkish blue, the background to my pop-up image the same blue and then change the colour of the text under the images to white. This means the text is still underlined, but in the same colour as the background and so you cannot see the underline! It works for me!!

Comment: I had `<a><span>text</span></a>` structure and did not understand what was the problem with the span. The problem was very simple. I applied `text-decoration: none` on the anchor tag.